# `yarn add` and `npm install` fail to create node_modules/.bin alias

Tags: node.js, npm-install, yarnpkg, bin

##### Steps to reproduce **working example**:

1. `git clone git@gitlab.com:garlik.io/ffmpeg.git /tmp/ffmpeg`
2. `yarn add /tmp/ffmpeg`

This creates `node_modules/.bin/ffmpeg` as expected.

##### Steps to reproduce **failing example**

1. `yarn add @garlikio/ffmpeg`

When installing from the repository, the bin alias is not created. ***However***, if I execute `yarn add @garlikio/ffmpeg --force` after the package has installed, the alias is created.

##### Relevant Stuff

- I'm installing from MaOS
- [package.json](https://gitlab.com/garlik.io/ffmpeg/-/blob/main/package.json)

  ```json
  "directories": {
    "bin": "bin"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "install": "node setup/install.js"
  },
  ```
- [setup/install.js:50](https://gitlab.com/garlik.io/ffmpeg/-/blob/main/setup/install.js)

  ```
  function createNodeModulesLink (ffmpegBinPath) {
    if (!fs.existsSync('bin')) {
      fs.mkdirSync('bin')
    }
    if (fs.existsSync('bin/ffmpeg')) {
      fs.unlinkSync('bin/ffmpeg')
    }
    fs.symlinkSync(ffmpegBinPath, 'bin/ffmpeg', 'file')
  }
  ```

Comment: Perhaps related to the order of execution of "link packages" and "install" https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3421#issuecomment-302080120

Comment: Changing `"install": "node setup/install.js"` to `"preinstall": node setup/install.js` fixes the issue on `npm install`, but not for `yarn add`

Answer (score 0):

The only way around this due to a yarn bug is to run `yarn --check-files --ignore-scripts` after `yarn install`.